# How to map the PostgreSQL Interval column type in Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, intervals, custom-type, column-types

Under PostgreSQL, I'm using `PersistentDuration` for the mapping between the sql type interval & duration but it doesn't work.

Another user found the same issue & come with his own class:

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index) 
        throws HibernateException, SQLException { 
    if (value == null) { 
        statement.setNull(index, Types.OTHER); 
    } else { 
        Long interval = ((Long) value).longValue(); 
        Long hours = interval / 3600; 
        Long minutes = (interval - (hours * 3600)) / 60; 
        Long secondes = interval - (hours * 3600) - minutes * 60; 
            statement.setString(index, "'"+ hours +":" 
                    + intervalFormat.format(minutes) + ":" 
                    + intervalFormat.format(secondes)+"'"); 

    } 
}
```

But it doesn't work with the real format because it suppose the interval pattern is only
"hh:mm:ss". That is not the case: see

Here some few real examples i need to parse from the database:

```
1 day 00:29:42
00:29:42
1 week 00:29:42
1 week 2 days  00:29:42
1 month 1 week 2 days  00:29:42
1 year 00:29:42
1 decade 00:29:42
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html

Have you a clean solution?

Answer (score 5):

This is a working solution for JPA, Hibernate (with annotations).

This is the beginning of the entity class (for the table that has Interval column):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_with_interval_col")
@TypeDef(name="interval", typeClass = Interval.class)
public class TableWithIntervalCol implements Serializable {
```

This is the interval column:

```
@Column(name = "interval_col",  nullable = false)
@Type(type = "interval")    
private Integer intervalCol;
```

And this is the Interval class:

```
package foo.bar.hibernate.type;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;
import org.postgresql.util.PGInterval;


/**
 * Postgres Interval type
 * 
 * @author bpgergo
 * 
 */
public class Interval implements UserType {
    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.OTHER };

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Integer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String interval = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (rs.wasNull() || interval == null) {
            return null;
        }
        PGInterval pgInterval = new PGInterval(interval);
        Date epoch = new Date(0l);
        pgInterval.add(epoch);
        return Integer.valueOf((int)epoch.getTime() / 1000);
    }

    public static String getInterval(int value){
        return new PGInterval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, value).getValue();
    }


    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            //this http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Inserting-Information-in-PostgreSQL-interval-td2175203.html#a2175205
            st.setObject(index, getInterval(((Integer) value).intValue()), Types.OTHER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

}
```

Comment: @ankit, you will have better chances to get a helpful answer if you [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather then asking your question in a comment

Comment: what data you are sending to `intervalCol` in ur example?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to write your own Hibernate custom type to map the PostgreSQL `interval` column to a Java `Duration` object. All you need to do is use the [Hibernate Ttypes](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project.

So, after adding the proper Hibernate dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You just have to use the `@TypeDef` annotation to register the [`PostgreSQLIntervalType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-interval-java-duration-hibernate/):

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDef(
    typeClass = PostgreSQLIntervalType.class,
    defaultForType = Duration.class
)
@TypeDef(
    typeClass = YearMonthDateType.class,
    defaultForType = YearMonth.class
)
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;
 
    private String title;
 
    @Column(
        name = "published_on",
        columnDefinition = "date"
    )
    private YearMonth publishedOn;
 
    @Column(
        name = "presale_period",
        columnDefinition = "interval"
    )
    private Duration presalePeriod;
 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public Book setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
 
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
 
    public Book setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        return this;
    }
 
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
 
    public Book setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        return this;
    }
 
    public YearMonth getPublishedOn() {
        return publishedOn;
    }
 
    public Book setPublishedOn(YearMonth publishedOn) {
        this.publishedOn = publishedOn;
        return this;
    }
 
    public Duration getPresalePeriod() {
        return presalePeriod;
    }
 
    public Book setPresalePeriod(Duration presalePeriod) {
        this.presalePeriod = presalePeriod;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, when persisting the `Book` entity:

```
entityManager.persist(
    new Book()
        .setIsbn("978-9730228236")
        .setTitle("High-Performance Java Persistence")
        .setPublishedOn(YearMonth.of(2016, 10))
        .setPresalePeriod(
            Duration.between(
                LocalDate
                    .of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 2)
                    .atStartOfDay(),
                LocalDate
                    .of(2016, Month.AUGUST, 25)
                    .atStartOfDay()
            )
        )
);
```

Hibernate will execute the proper SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO book (
    isbn,
    presale_period,
    published_on,
    title,
    id
)
VALUES (
    '978-9730228236',
    '0 years 0 mons 297 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs',
    '2016-10-01',
    'High-Performance Java Persistence',
    1
)
```

When fetching the `Book` entity, we can see that the `Duration` attribute is properly fetched from the database:

```
Book book = entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .bySimpleNaturalId(Book.class)
    .load("978-9730228236");
 
assertEquals(
    Duration.between(
        LocalDate
            .of(2015, Month.NOVEMBER, 2)
            .atStartOfDay(),
        LocalDate
            .of(2016, Month.AUGUST, 25)
            .atStartOfDay()
    ),
    book.getPresalePeriod()
);
```

Comment: No need for an external library ... at least not with Hibernate6. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77508034/1504556). I get that this may have been written when Hibernate5 was current.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just turn it into a numeric and map to a Long?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM my_interval)
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a date_part / extract function which you can use to return different fields, epoch being one of them. When extracting the epoch from an interval, you receive the number of seconds contained in the interval, and from there you can convert however you wish. I lost my experience with Hibernate, but you can do it this way:

```
SELECT
    average_interval_between_airings
  , date_part('epoch', average_interval_between_airings) / 60 as minutes
  , date_part('epoch', average_interval_between_airings) as seconds
FROM shows;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you should have a day followed by hours:minutes:seconds. So changing the code to something like the following assuming you never need to have more then 23 hours 59 minutes in the interval.

```
statement.setString(index, "'0 "+ hours +":" 
+ intervalFormat.format(minutes) + ":" 
+ intervalFormat.format(secondes)+"'");
```

I am not able to test this code since I don't have PostGreSql installed. For another discussion on this same issue see the following link, although you would have to modify the code provided to handle seconds. That shouldn't be much of a problem though.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2348558&sid=95488ce561e7efec8a2950f76ae4741c

Comment: No it is mandatory to have a day.And there not only the keywork day (year, month, week,.. see the link above) Here some real example from the database:
-1 day 00:29:42
-00:29:42
-1 week 00:29:42
1 week 2 days  00:29:42
1 month 1 week 2 days  00:29:42
-1 year 00:29:42
1 decade 00:29:42

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has been able to do this for quite some time now.

#### Hibernate 5

Hibernate 5 had native support for `Duration` on the Java side of things but it would expect that you would store it in a SQL DECIMAL column in the database, for example in PostgreSQL a column of type `numeric`. It would simply read and write the `Duration` value as a decimal number. (number of second with fractions). This makes sense as by this strategy Hibernate was able to always support `Duration` regardless if the target database had any real support for a true SQL INTERVAL column type.

#### Hibernate 6 (current)

There is now native support for PostgreSQL `interval` column type.
However, for historical reasons (read: no desire to break existing applications) you need to explicitly tell Hibernate that are using your database's SQL INTERVAL feature, if any. If you don't do this then Hibernate will still do as it did in v5, i.e. it will attempt to write to the column as a decimal. Obviously this will not work if your database is PostgreSQL and your column is of type `interval`.

Your entity class should simply look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mouse_observations")
public class MyTestEntity {
    ...

    @Column(name = "my_duration", columnDefinition = "interval")
    private Duration myDuration;
    ...
}
```

Important:

You need to set the property `hibernate.type.preferred_duration_jdbc_type=INTERVAL_SECOND` to let Hibernate know that you are using your database's INTERVAL type.

Note: The `columnDefinition` that I put in there is only to make it clear what the corresponding database column type is in my example. I don't think Hibernate uses the `columnDefinition` for anything outside of the DDL scenario. In other words: you can leave it out.