# How to format Interval type to HH:MM format?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using oracle DB with below column

`START_TIME INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)`

I am using jdbc template in java code to access this value using the row mapper and getString() method like below: (I am running a basic select query to fetch values from DB)

```
String startTime = rs.getString("START_TIME");
```

and the value I get is in this format

```
System.out.println(startTime); // 0 9:30:0.0
```

I am not able to format this value in the **HH:MM** format string. I do not need the seconds as I am ignoring that value. So what I want is something like this **09:30**

[Found this which looks similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236798/how-to-represent-oracle-interval-in-java) but I am using swagger open API yaml based generation for DTOs and don't know how can I achieve this. Also, I am not using hibernate. It's plain JDBC Template.

**EDIT:** Observed that when I have `+00 11:00:00.000000` in the DB, the `rs.getString("START_TIME")` fetches `0 11:0:0.0` and when `+00 09:30:00.000000` it fetches `0 9:30:0.0` but my requirement is `11:00` and `09:30`. Hope this helps a little more.

Comment: so, let  me see if i got your question, you have a string like ***"09:30:0.0"*** , but you need something like ***"09:30"***   ?

Comment: Are you ever going to get intervals of 1 day or more?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I have a string of  **0 9:30:0.0** and I want **09:30** I tried string manipulation but I am not sure if that is the best way to do it. Not sure if I am even handling the oracle's interval type correctly.

Comment: @MT0 No that is not going to happen. It's just about the hours and minutes. That's why we have DAY(0)

Comment: That's why I asked. If you were expecting `1 9:30` to be output as `33:30` then that's a very different solution to just converting `0 X:YY` to `0X:YY`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that manipulating the string value is the easiest and simplest solution, so I will present an alternative solution.

From the Oracle documentation for the [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C) and from the definition of column `START_TIME` in your question, the column values cannot span more than one day nor can they contain fractional seconds.

From the Oracle [JDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/accessing-and-manipulating-Oracle-data.html#GUID-1AF80C90-DFE6-4A3E-A407-52E805726778), the datatype `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` maps to the java class `oracle.sql.INTERVALDS`. (This is one of the classes in the Oracle JDBC driver JAR file.)

From the [*javadoc*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/INTERVALDS.html) of class `oracle.sql.INTERVALDS`:

> The internal data for this object is stored as a 11 byte array in the super class' storage area. The bytes are arranged as follows:
>
> ```
>  Byte       Represents
>    0         High byte of day
>    1         2nd high byte of day
>    2         3rd high byte of day
>    3         least byte of day   
>    4         hour val + 60     
>    5         min + 60
>    6         sec + 60
>    7         High byte of Fractional second
>    8         2nd high byte of Fractional Second
>    9         3rd high byte of Fractional Second
>    10        least byte of Fractional Second
> ```

You know that only bytes 4, 5 and 6 are relevant because of the definition of column `START_TIME`, i.e. zero days and zero fractional seconds. But since you wrote in your question that you are ignoring the seconds, that means only bytes 4 and 5 are relevant. Hence the code for retrieving the value from the `ResultSet` and converting it to a string in your desired format is:

```java
INTERVALDS intervalDS = (INTERVALDS) rs.getObject("START_TIME");
byte[] bytes = intervalDS.toBytes();
int hour = bytes[4] - 60;
int minute = bytes[5] - 60;
String result = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
```

Comment: This somewhat serves the purpose, but when the DB has `+00 11:00:00.000000` the `rs.getObject("START_TIME")` fetches `0 11:0:0.0` but I want `11:00` Any leads on this?

Comment: @Sudhanshu `rs.getObject("START_TIME")` **does NOT** fetch `0 11:0:0.0`. It fetches an object. More precisely, it fetches an instance of `oracle.sql.INTERVALDS`. The string representation of the object is `0 11:0:0.0`.

Comment: Agree, I tried Syso on it and it gives me `0 11:0:0.0` and also if you can see my edit in the question, that problem I am still facing with this approach as well. So, for example instead of `11:00` I get `11:0` and for `09:30` I get `9:30` when I do `bytes[x] - 60`

Answer (score 0):

Find the substring from after the first space character to the second `:` colon character and left-pad it with a zero so that it is 5 characters long.

```java
public static String getHoursMinutesFromInterval( final String time )
{
  String hhmm = time.replaceAll( "^0 (\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}):\\d+\\.\\d+$", "0$1" );
  if ( hhmm.length() > 5 )
  {
    hhmm = hhmm.substring(1, 6);
  }
  return hhmm;
}
```

Comment: I still get `11:0` can you check my EDIT in the question. Hopefully it will add some value to it.