# How to format Oracle's Interval Datatype to HH:MM format?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have a table in Oracle DB with below column

```
START_TIME INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)
```

I am running a basic select query to fetch values from DB. I am using JDBC template and getString() like below

```
String startTime = rs.getString("START_TIME");
```

When I have `+00 11:00:00.000000` in the DB, the `rs.getString("START_TIME")` fetches `0 11:0:0.0`

and when `+00 09:30:00.000000` it fetches `0 9:30:0.0` but my requirement is **11:00** and **09:30**

Can someone help me with how can I do this formatting?

I have already tried the below:

[How to represent Oracle Interval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236798/how-to-represent-oracle-interval-in-java) - but I am using swagger open API yaml based generation for DTOs and don't know how can I achieve this. Also, I am not using hibernate. It's plain JDBC Template.

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62084887/8938332) - but it didn't help me

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970249/format-interval-with-to-char

Comment: Do you need this just to display to users in prefferred format or to transfer that data to other apps?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I would prefer not to do this in SQL, we want to achieve this in Java code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these variants:

```java
// add this function: it converts intervalDS to Time/Timestamp
    public static Time intervalDStoTime(INTERVALDS intervalds) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat intervalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        java.util.Date parsedDate = intervalFormat.parse(intervalds.stringValue());
        Time time = new java.sql.Time(parsedDate.getTime());
        // or you can replace previous line with this one if yu will need timestamp:
        // Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        return time;
    }

//...
// your code:
    //Original:
    oracle.sql.INTERVALDS startTime = rs.getINTERVALDS("START_TIME");
    System.out.println("Original:" + startTime);
    // 1: interval to time:
    Time time = intervalDStoTime(startTime);
    System.out.println("ToTime: " + time);
    // 2: + format
    System.out.println("ToTime + format: " + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(time));
    // 3: format bytes
    byte[] bytes = startTime.toBytes();
    int hour = bytes[4] - 60;
    int minute = bytes[5] - 60;
    String hhmm = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    System.out.println("toBytes + format: " + hhmm);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the `rs.getINTERVALDS("START_TIME");` gives compilation issue `The method getINTERVALDS(String) is undefined for the type ResultSet`. Have you tried this code if it works?

Comment: Yes, of course, that was tested with actual oracle driver 19. What oracle ojdbc driver do you use?

Comment: @sudoss you should use OracleResultSet: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleResultSet.html

Comment: How do I find out the ojdbc driver? If you mean the driver class name then I am using `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: @sudoss ok, then just replace ResultSet type of variable rs with OracleResultSet

Comment: Then how do I implement the rowmapper interface? If gives compilation issue on the mapRow method

Comment: Read the link above: OracleResultSet extends java.sql.ResultSet. So just cast ResultSet to OracleResultSet when needed.