# SQL datatype for java.time.Duration

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, jdbc, duration

I have following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Notification {

    private Duration deliveryTimeLimit;

    public Duration getDeliveryTimeLimit() {
        return deliveryTimeLimit;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTimeLimit(Duration deliveryTimeLimit) {
        this.deliveryTimeLimit = deliveryTimeLimit;
    }

}
```

I'd like to store Duration to database.

What datatype should I use in Oracle database?

When I choose `NUMBER`, then I have to specify `1 minute` as `60000000000 nanoseconds` while loading data from csv file.

Answer (score 2):

INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND data type is your friend here. 
See: [How to represent Oracle Interval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236798/how-to-represent-oracle-interval-in-java)

Additionaly, you may check Oracle database data type: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F8686599-B7AE-477D-8A58-FA0AA8B2C348

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> select interval '1' minute from dual;

INTERVAL'1'MINUTE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00 00:01:00
```