# Hibernate: How to map tsrange to Java entity column/columns?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to use `tsrange` as type for `effective_range` column and for `valid_range` column (transaction start and end timestamp) and use it in temporal queries.

Is there any type to map tsrange to a entity's column/columns?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. I am trying to figure hibernate specific custom mapping

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Those answers refer to JDBC or direct use of the entity manager., The poster asked for Hibernate entity mappings.

Comment: I think the following would be a better avenue for researching
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945615/how-to-map-the-type-interval-in-hibernate